# Android String and Style Resource Not giving desired change

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I'm developing an android app and I'm trying to use a string resource to store my table title and a style to store my TextAppearance as below:

string:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">DatabaseApp</string>
    <string name="table_title">2019 Staff Database</string>
</resources>
```

style:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">20sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Question:** Whenever I introduce the...**style="@style/TextStyle"**...the table title text changes to TextView, I cant figure out the issue, somebody to help me out. What could be the problem?

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/table_title"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    style="@style/TextStyle"/>

    <TableRow>
        <!--My other xml codes here-->

    </TableRow>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the table title text changes to TextView`? after applying the style what is the text value of the TextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared in your `style.xml`:

```
<item name="android:textColor">20sp</item>
```

I believe android:textColor will not accept a `sp` or `dp` value, rather use a color in hex or any resource existing in `colors.xml`

Comment: Let me know if it works! I'd really appreciate if you can accept it as answer :)